# RelativeLayout Stack Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I would like to align two buttons on the bottom of a relative layout that is wrapped inside of a linear layout.

I am unable to get the view favorites button to be on top of the search button. There is a big space as you can see in this image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/SearchRestaurantsCity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantSearchCity" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etRestaurantSearchCity" />
<TextView
    android:text="@string/SearchRestaurantsState"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantSearchState" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etRestaurantSearchState" />
<TextView
    android:text="@string/SearchRestaurantsCategories"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantSearchCategories" />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spRestaurantSearchCategories" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:text="@string/btnViewFavoriteRestaurants"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnViewFavoriteRestaurants"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_below="btnSearchRestaurants" />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/btnSearchRestaurants"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchRestaurants"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to put the first button I can see inside RelativeLayout, I'd try to change the following line:

android:layout_below="btnSearchRestaurants" />

for this one:

android:layout_above="@+id/btnSearchRestaurants" />

Part of the space is reserved for all the elements of the layout I can see inside the LinearLayout,and the + is because the button btnSearchRestaurants is below so it is not created yet

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things wrong with the XML.

For starters, you can't refer to the button `btnSearchRestaurants` before it's defined.

Secondly, you've defined `btnSearchRestaurants` to align-parent-bottom, and then tried to define that `btnViewFavoriteRestaurants` would be below that button. It should be above it (as per your description).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at

```
android:layout_below="btnSearchRestaurants"
```

It should be

```
android:layout_below="@id/btnSearchRestaurants"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml code I think you should correct this line

```
android:layout_below="btnSearchRestaurants"
```

as you want it to be above the Search Restaurants button it should be

```
android:layout_above="@id/btnSearchRestaurants"
```

I changed below to above for obvious reasons (you want it above the other button not below it) and added @id/ because you will be searching for the button id.